# Resource Utilisation

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have created an compute engine instance in Google Cloud environment. The instance hosts a service. Using some script I load tested the service by sending http requests at different load level. Now I want to visualize the resource utilization in R. Is there a simple API that I can use to fetch CPU utilization between X and Y time? X & Y are load test time.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [Google Cloud Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/getting-started).

The`compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization` [metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics) returns the percentage of the allocated CPU that is currently in use on the instance.

The`compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/usage_time` metric is a delta type and you can specify the time interval for CPU usage. You can try these APIs at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/getting-started#try_it) or at [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/cloudmonitoring/v2beta2/cloudmonitoring.timeseries.list).